# CreatePlatformSocket() failed: Operation not permitted (1) during facebook login Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-login

I have an error:

```
E/chromium: [ERROR:socket_posix.cc(94)] CreatePlatformSocket() failed: Operation not permitted (1)
    [ERROR:socket_posix.cc(94)] CreatePlatformSocket() failed: Operation not permitted (1)
```

when I click "login with facebook" in my android app.

Androidmanifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.inzynierka">

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity
            android:name=".PremiumActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".UserPanelActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DailyChallengeActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MyProgressActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".UserPanelActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="UserPanelActivity"
                android:value=".UserPanelActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".UserPanelActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".UserPanelActivity">

            <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.login.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

LoginActivity (I am using built-in login activity):

```
package com.example.inzynierka.ui.login;

import android.app.Activity;

import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.StringRes;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.inzynierka.R;
import com.example.inzynierka.UserPanelActivity;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;


public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LoginViewModel loginViewModel;
    public static CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new LoginViewModelFactory())
                .get(LoginViewModel.class);
        final EditText usernameEditText = findViewById(R.id.username);
        final EditText passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.password);
        final Button loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login);
        final ProgressBar loadingProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.loading);

        loginViewModel.getLoginFormState().observe(this, new Observer<LoginFormState>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable LoginFormState loginFormState) {
                if (loginFormState == null) {
                    return;
                }
                loginButton.setEnabled(loginFormState.isDataValid());
                if (loginFormState.getUsernameError() != null) {
                    usernameEditText.setError(getString(loginFormState.getUsernameError()));
                }
                if (loginFormState.getPasswordError() != null) {
                    passwordEditText.setError(getString(loginFormState.getPasswordError()));
                }
            }
        });

        loginViewModel.getLoginResult().observe(this, new Observer<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable LoginResult loginResult) {
                if (loginResult == null) {
                    return;
                }
                loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (loginResult.getError() != null) {
                    showLoginFailed(loginResult.getError());
                }
                if (loginResult.getSuccess() != null) {
                    updateUiWithUser(loginResult.getSuccess());
                }
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);

                //Complete and destroy login activity once successful
                finish();
            }
        });

        TextWatcher afterTextChangedListener = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // ignore
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // ignore
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                loginViewModel.loginDataChanged(usernameEditText.getText().toString(),
                        passwordEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        };
        usernameEditText.addTextChangedListener(afterTextChangedListener);
        passwordEditText.addTextChangedListener(afterTextChangedListener);
        passwordEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    loginViewModel.login(usernameEditText.getText().toString(),
                            passwordEditText.getText().toString());
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                loginViewModel.login(usernameEditText.getText().toString(),
                        passwordEditText.getText().toString());
                UserPanel();
            }
        });
    }

    private void UserPanel() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, UserPanelActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void updateUiWithUser(LoggedInUserView model) {
        String welcome = getString(R.string.welcome) + model.getDisplayName();
        // TODO : initiate successful logged in experience
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), welcome, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void showLoginFailed(@StringRes Integer errorString) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Fragment (only this is changed in Fragment):

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_facebook, container, false);
        LoginButton loginButton = view.findViewById(R.id.login_fbbutton);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_birthday");
        // If using in a fragment
        loginButton.setFragment(this);
        // Other app specific specialization

        // Callback registration
        loginButton.registerCallback(LoginActivity.callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                System.out.println("Success");

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                System.out.println("onCancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
            }
        });
        return view;

    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

After MainActivity I am in LoginActivity and when I click Facebook Button, a window appears for a while and then hides. 
Of course, I was doing everything like it's written on Facebook for Developers.

By the way, in my buildgradle I have:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.33.0'
```

because then CallbackManager only works. There are errors on newer version.

Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: What's the version of your target and compile sdk verstion in `build.gradle`?

Comment: Actually it started to work but I need to fix code with displaying nickname on screen. I did a lot of things but switching something in build.gradle did a job.